# $E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)\nRightarrow E(|X_n-X|)\rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables and $X$ be another random variable, then as far as I know $$E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)\nRightarrow E(|X_n-X|)\rightarrow 0$$ **always**. 
But I am not getting an example. Can somone provide me one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

- $X_n = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$ with 100% probability
- $X=1$ with probability .5 and $x = 0$ with probability .5

That two random variables have the same expectation in no way implies that the expected absolute difference between them is zero. Basically, it's a jazzed up version of the rather obvious idea that $ \sum_i x_i = \sum_i y_i$ is not the same as $x_i = y_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: The $E(|X_n-X|)$ inyour example is $={1\over 2}$ . Am I right?

Comment: @Qwerty That is correct.